# error while trying to run java project through virtual box on jenkins

Tags: java

I'm using oracle virtual box connected it to ssh and try to make a small java project which I am unable because I face some errors like

```
error while writing Simple: Simple.class (Permission denied)
class Simple{  
^
1 error
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm trying to run java project on jenkins

[image]

Comment: *error while writing Simple: Simple.class (Permission denied)* is self explainatory.

Comment: Beside the link to the screenshot. please add the error message text to your question directly.